# Can I json_encode a PHP array and get values as JS RegExp objects?

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex

I have some regex patterns stored as strings inside a PHP array. I need them to be outputted as JavaScript RegExp objects. Is there any way to do this by using PHP's `json_encode`?

Example:

```php
$array = [
   'regex' => '/some-regex/' 
];
return json_encode( $array );
```

Desired output:

```js
{"regex": /some-regex/}
```

Current output:

```js
{"regex": "/some-regex/"}
```

Comment: You cannot create JavaScript data structures using PHP, no.

Comment: `{"regex": /some-regex/}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: You can still use it even if it is a string by passing it in the constructor of [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Example: `let pattern = new RegExp(theRegexString)` and then use `pattern` instead of the regex.

Comment: @AbraCadaver (yikes :-) - deriving from the OPs terminology, once converted from JSON to a JavaScript object, it is valid to have `{regex: new RegExp(/some/)}`. In otherwords, have a RegExp Object as an object property.

Comment: Once you get `{"regex": "/some-regex/"}`, just loop over them with the `new RegExp()` constructor, which takes a string representing a regular expression.

Comment: Is it just me, or are we all missing the question: _Is there any way to do this by using PHP's json_encode?_ The answer is no.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - IMHO, the first and the second comment answers that pretty clearly.

Comment: Right - oh, I made the first comment :-). Going on and on about using `new Regexp()` isn't necessary.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - :-) I think most of the comments were written at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly with `json_encode`. All PHP does is create arrays and objects containing simple scalar types. It cannot create JS objects like `RegExp` or call JS functions directly. If *all* you're going to pass is that sample data in the question you can always do

```
$array = [
   'regex' => '/some-regex/' 
];
$js_string = '';
foreach($array as $key => $value) $js_string .= '"' . $key . '": new RegExp("' . $value ' "),';
return '{' . $js_string . '}';
```

That's **really** clunky code and, of course, it falls apart if `$array` contains anything but regular expressions (and it assumes that everything in there is safe for JS). But if that's *all* you have to do...

## Wait! Is there a better way?

Indeed there is. The better thing to do is have `json_encode` do it's thing (it's kinda made to handle JSON) and then have your JS create the objects itself

```
let regex_list = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;
let myregex = {};
regex_list.forEach(function(regex, index) {
    myregex[index] = new RegExp(regex);
});
```

This is a much cleaner solution. We don't have to worry about the data coming from PHP, so JS can take it from there and build a JS object that holds all the `RegExp` objects you want to create

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Because you're passing through JSON structure which just wraps-data. A string by json standard starts with " and ends with ", otherwise it's a number or an array for istance.

I wondered a similiar thing about it. I wanted to create a function for JS  but on server side with php, based on the result. Usually when you face this problem it means you've to rethink a bit the structure of your page/app.

However as they pointed out in the comments to your question, you might find workarounds to build the object locally once the HTTP request is ended.

Also would recommend reading this: [Security issues JSON with eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Security_considerations)